# list index out of range error: urbandict.py

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple word guard. I have installed *urbandict.py* in Python 2.7.
This API handles data through a JSON object. If the word is in the urban dictionary I want true, otherwise false.

```
import urbandict 
ur = urbandict.define("ice")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmurp_000\Desktop\wordFuntcion.py", line 15, in <module>
    ur = urbandict.define("ice")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urbandict.py", line 86, in define
    urbanDictParser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 114, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 152, in goahead
    if i < j: self.handle_data(rawdata[i:j])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urbandict.py", line 72, in handle_data
    self.translations[-1]['example'] += data.replace('\r', '\n')
**IndexError: list index out of range**
```

I have tried to handle indexing but the program does not make it that far.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using [this github project](https://github.com/novel/py-urbandict)?

Comment: It looks like `urbandictionary.com` changed its html markup (You could [see old markup on webarchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140101045756/http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ice). Here's [`urbandictionary.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9903390) that works  for the current html markup. Feel free to adapt it into a pull request for [`py-urbandict`](https://github.com/novel/py-urbandict).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In urbandict.py in the handle_data method try replacing...

```
   elif self.inside_example_section is True:
       self.translations[-1]['example'] += data.replace('\r', '\n')
```

with

```
   elif self.inside_example_section is True:
       if len(self.translations) >= 1:
            self.translations[-1]['example'] += data.replace('\r', '\n')
```

Comment: Editing a library you downloaded when you hit an exception trying to use it is **not** usually the recommended (or sane) way to fix the exception. If any new dev came behind OP and knew this library, they would expect it to work the way it does from git, and would be unaware of this modification (possibly causing problems).

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to http://urbandictionary.com has changed its html markup recently. [Development version (urbandict 0.2)](https://github.com/novel/py-urbandict) supports the new html markup. You could install it using `pip`:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/novel/py-urbandict#egg=urbandict
```

Example:

```
$ urbandicli Honorificabilitudinitatibus

1. honorificabilitudinitatibus   honorableness  Used by Shakespeare in Loves Labors Lost (Costartd;  Act V Scene I)
  Examples:
  *  For thou art not so long by the head as
    honorificabilitudinitatibus: thou art easier swallowed than a
    flap-dragon.
```